# Remove "Personalization" pane from Alexa Testing Web Interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, personalization

I am currently working on Amazon Alexa via the Amazon Web Developer Console, and they have added a new "personalization" feature that I dont need. It is not enabled for this skill, and I dont intend to do so. Nevertheless, the viewing window for this feature takes up more than half of my screen in the testing window, and I cannot remove it, nor scroll it out of view, which leads to me being unable to properly view the important parts of the testing page, the Skill IO and the display.

Has anyone had this problem? How can I get rid of this personalization window

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA2kV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Terrible design, you can't for now (unless manually removing it on your browser).

Submit a feedback on the page (bottom left) so they will be aware and fix it soon hopefully:
[image]